# Plot sine wave on Console (native C)

Tags: c++, plot, trigonometry

Guy's, I need help... I have to plot a sine wave on the console for my university class. But i struggle a bit with the if's.. Why does the second if statement not take the new "y_1" from the first if/else statement? Maybe someone can explain me, what's my mistake in thinking ^^
Thanks a lot

```
#include <iostream>//Bibliothek fuer IO (Input-Output)
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int i,j=0;
    double k,l=0.0;
    int y_1=0;
    double x,y_=0.0;
    char a[80][24];
    for(i=0; i<25; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<81; j++)
        {
            a[j][i]='.';
        }
    }
    
    for(k=0; k<81; k++)
    {
        for(l=0; l<24; l++)
        {
            x=(k/80)*2*M_PI;
            if(sin(x)>=0)
            {
                y_=12-(sin(x)*12);
                int y_1=y_;
            }
            else
            {
                y_=12+(sin(x)*12);
                int y_1=y_;
            }
            if(y_1==l)
            {
                int k=k;
                int l=l;
                a[k][l]='*';
            }
        }   
    }
    
    for(i=0; i<25; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<81; j++)
        {
            cout<<a[j][i];
        }
    cout<<endl;
    }
    
    cout<<"Quit:Press Enter"<<endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged C when it is obviously C++?

Comment: `int k = k;` : what is this supposed to do?? You're trying to initialize a variable with itself, which is of course pointless.

Comment: I have done int k=k; to convert the double k to the int k

Comment: It doesn't work like this. The 'k' in `int k=k;`  is not the same as the `k` in `double k,l=0.0;`, they have different scopes. The only thing they have in common is their name. Read about [variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)

Comment: Your array only contains `[80]`. But your loop is `< 81`.

Answer (score 1):

All variables have a scope.

```
// y_1 is not visible here, because y_1 is not introduced yet
int y_1=0;   // the first y_1 is initialised (line 11)

{ // <-- this begins a new scope

   int y_1 = 123;  // you declare a new y_1 in the newly created scope

} // <-- this ends the nested scope

// that y_1, that was initialised to 123 is not visible here anymore
if (y_1 == ...) { // y_1 == 0
}
```

You are having a local `int y_1 = 0` on line 11. Then you are having a separate `int y_1=12-...` on line 30 and one completely different `int y_1=12+...` on line 35. Removing the `int` allows the different branches to modify that `y_1`, which you are comparing on line 37.